# Can `git push --mirror` create a new repo?

Tags: git, version-control

I cloned a repo from, say, server A with `git clone --mirror https://server-A/foo-repo.git`. Now I need to push this repo to server B. Server B doesn't have that repo created yet. My push command is like this: `git push --mirror git@server-B.com:some-name/foo-repo.git`.

Unfortunately, I am getting an error as below after the push:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So, does that mean there must exist a repo on server B in order for the push to work? If so, then the question is how I can create a repo as the user `git`?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git push` cannot create a new repository, no matter what arguments you pass it. It expects to find an already existing repository on the other end.